# Can I ask this type question in Unix&Linux?

Tags: support

I read many article about operating system, and find many following situations:

[image]

You see, there is `*nix` systems in the web page, why not the Unix? why there is `*` to replace it?

Because I found many case, so I doubt if there is other meanings here.

So, I want to ask this type question in Unix&Linux site, but I don't know if is in legal.

Comment: This is the wrong Meta site for this question; *\*nix* here refers to all OSes ending in *nix*, so Linux and UNIX, etc. as well as many other Unix-like OSes.

Comment: Side note asking non-researched Q on any SE site would likely lead to downvotes - https://www.bing.com/search?q=what+star+nix+means - gives - https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-unix-and-*nix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The good news is that you don't have to, because someone already did: [Why is there a * When There is Mention of Unix Throughout the Internet?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2342/why-is-there-a-when-there-is-mention-of-unix-throughout-the-internet).

There is a legitimate historical question there that is on-topic. There probably aren't very many other questions of the same sort, but this is one that has been addressed.